# WINAPI: How to avoid scaling of Window depending on Monitor scale factor?

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, mfc

Windows 10.

I have 2 monitors. Lets call them the LM (left) and the RM (right). 
I set for the LM scale 150% and for the RM I set a 100% scale factor.

I found out that if more than 50% of an application's window is on the LM then a pixels of that window are scaled to a 150%, but if more than a 50% of the window is on the RM then it scales to a 100%. So it means that scaling of a Application's window depends on how much of it's part is on the LM or the RM.

So I have the following questions:

1. How to avoid that behaviour and make my Window to be with a constant scale factor?
2. How to get a scale factor from monitors?
3. How to set this scale factor to my application's window.

Using WINAPI of course.

Comment: [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows).

Comment: For 1, if you mark your app as per-monitor DPI aware then Windows won't autoscale it and you can render it however you want.

Comment: Start by reading the documentation on DPI aware development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of high-dpi support.  Applications that don't declare DPI awareness in their manifest or at startup get automatic scaling based on the scale factor the user has set for his **primary** monitor.

If you just want to turn off all this automatic scaling stuff, you can start with this call at the start of your program (i.e. first line of WinMain):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellscalingapi.h>

int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
     SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE);
```

Then link with `shcore.lib`.

The above works on Windows 8.1 and up only. So on Windows 7 or Vista, you'd just call `SetProcessDPIAware()` at startup instead.

Everything else you asked about at the links below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/C9488338-D863-45DF-B5CB-7ED9B869A5E2